# Minimize Value of Function with Constrain

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Let $x$ and $y$ be real number with $xy\neq-1$ and $$\frac{x^7y+xy^7}{1+x^5y^5}=4$$
>   What is the minimum value of $x^2+y^2?$

I've been trying to solve it by Lagrange Multiplier but it's getting more complicated. Since this is math contest practice problem, isn't there any inequality theorem I could use?

Comment: which equation system did you got?

Comment: the result is really not nice

Comment: Try use new variables $u=x+y$ and $v=xy$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I'm not sure I understand your question but I used $f(x,y)=x^7y-4x^5y^5+xy^7-4$ to minimize $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2,$ and yes I don't think Lagrange solved this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps but the constraint also writes $\dfrac{xy(x^2+y^2)(x^4-x^2y^2+y^4)}{1+x^5y^5}=4$ (the function to minimize appears).

Comment: @MichaelGaluza okay, I'll try. But isn't it seems tedious?

Comment: @anderstood wow, I honestly never thought to factorize it.

Comment: I would be surprised that this could be reasonably solved by hand, and has a closed-form solution. Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's answer is probably the most robust technique. If it does not satisfy you, tell us why.

Comment: @anderstood since this is math olympiad problem so I thought it can be solved using some inequality theorem.

Comment: in the general case such a trick can't often be found

Comment: Which Math Olympiad and when?  It would be really surprising to have someone solve this one by hand.